# What table in the database contains hooks in Liferay?

Tags: liferay-6

I know portlets are in Layouts, but I cannot find hooks.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that hooks are added to the database in Liferay. What do you want to achieve with this information?

Comment: `Layout` contains information of what portlets are on the page. And when the portlet is deployed the information is stored in `Portlet` table. For hook there is no such table since it overrides liferay's default, so on deployment the changes are made to liferay. I would also like to know what you want to achieve through or is it just curiosity as to how Liferay manages hooks :-)